# How to update only the last elements's first index in a List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Consider the following code:

```
public void updateUser(Login login) {
    UserExposableDO userExposableDO= new UserExposableDO(login);
    for (int i = 0; i < (userList.size()-1); i++){
        userList.set(i,userExposableDO);
    }
}
```

This code updates each and every user in the list. 
The userList gets filled whenever a user logs in. How do I update the status for each user after he logs out. 
In simple words, I need to set the status of the latest or last user. The index of the status is 3.

Comment: I might be missing something but i see that the loop wouldnt access the last element. Are u sure u want the code to be this way??

Comment: You want userList to contain the same user?now it overwrites each element with new user. You should better use add method to add new user to list and after logout you delete last. Maybe you need Stack structure for this, so latest out?

Comment: @SamDJava I am ready to change my code.

Comment: @cyan I have an add method for new users. I have just shown updateUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to set the status of the latest or last user.

Just looking at your question. Just get the last element of the list. And update it's first index.

```
 list.get(list.size()-1)// now you will get the last user
```

then

```
 userList.set(0,userExposableDO)
```